# How do I get a list of primary links by language?

Tags: 6, routes, i18n-l10n

I have been digging different drupal 6 functions such as menu_primary_links(), menu_tree_page_data(), menu_tree(), menu_get_item() etc but I can't find how it is done.

Does anybody have an idea? I need it badly :(

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Drupal is this for?

Comment: this is for drupal 6